# Spark cluster Adding Number in sequence to every line in a file

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a file which contains names in each line , I want to add numbers in sequence to each line. 
For eg if a file is like this

```
a  
b
c
d
```

I want it to achieve this

```
a,1
b,2
c,3
d,4
```

I have write this code to achieve this

```
val lines = sc.textFile("data.txt")
val pair = lines.zipWithIndex().map{case(i,line) => i.toString +","+line}
pair.collect()
```

But As you know , Spark distributes it task across different clusters. So I am not sure that this will work.So can anyone please tell me how can i achieve this? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what is the relationship between data and line number

Comment: In the file data.txt 'a' in the first line, 'b' is in the second line. So basically i am adding the line number

Comment: Do you experience any problems with `zipWithIndex`? It should work as you expect even is tasks are distributed across nodes.

Comment: What is the actual problem? Looking at the code this should work just fine. Are you experiencing otherwise?

Comment: Actually I didn't try it yet. But I was trying to know why will it work? . I mean for eg, 'a' will run on node1 , 'b' run on node 2 and so on . So should it not be like a1 , b1 or  similar to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you will run this code you will get an output you are expecting. 
Even when spark distributes its task across cluster but that do not affect anything programmatically. In case of your example if you are running with 2 worker node then file will be divided into two partitions which will be stored on each respective worker node. Now when program will run and when driver will come across zipWithIndex it will make sure that both the worker will have information about the other partition of the file since it is requirement of zipWithIndex.

In spark different transformation and actions have different requirements and master node make sure that those requirements are fulfilled like distinct need the shuffling of data to make sure that there is only one copy.

Another thing if you only want to make pair of word with line number then you do not need map. Only this will also work

```
pair = lines.zipWithIndex();
```

I ran the example in java with the above line of code without map and it gave me correct output. Although line number started with 0.But still it proves the point that number of worker node will not have any effect on displaying line number in order.

```
// output of worker 1 part-00000
    a,0
    b,1

//output of worker 2 part-00001
    c,2
    d,3
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation